# How to find List element with max member variable A, then output its member variable B?

Tags: c#, linq, max

I have a 100-element List of class objects. The class has 2 member variables, both Doubles. I want to sort the list by Class1.A ascending, then within a specified sublist of this sorted list (e.g. elements 5 through 60), output Class1.A for max Class1.B.

I understand this should be very doable in LINQ, but I'm very new to LINQ outside of running SQL queries in C#, and I haven't found a tutorial/Q&A that's really helped me make this work.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
public class Class1{
  public Double A;
  public Double B;

  public void CompareByA(Class1 C1, Class1 C2)
  { 
     return C1.A.CompareTo(C2.A);  
  }
}

public Double FindMaxAWithinSubset(List<Class1> L, int X, int Y)
{
  L.Sort(Class1.CompareByA);
  // Once L has been sorted by A, within the sublist of L with element         
  // indices between X and Y, find the element with maximum B, and output its A.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ `OrderBy`, so you don't need to use `Sort`. First `OrderBy` by property A, then you can use `Where` to select item with index from X to Y.

Then you `OrderByDescending` in property B. This way to make the item which maximun B in top of list. You just get `First` to get the result.

```
   var result = list.OrderBy(x => x.A)
                    .Where((x, index) => index >= X && index <= Y)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.B)
                    .First().A;
```

Comment: Thank you! That cleans things up very nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use LINQ extensions, so I would do this.  Not sure what the SQL - looking linq expression would be.

```
Double maxAValueInSubSet = L.OrderBy(x => x.A).Skip(X).Take(Y-X).Max(x => x.B).Single().A;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I've been looking for!

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = myInstance.OrderBy(x => x.A).Skip(5).Take(55).Max(y => y.B).FirstOrDefault();
```

What this does is order by the double A, skips the first 5, takes the next 55, then selects the max of the remaining B.